# Can you have two projects of different types (i.e. a desktop project and a web project) in a single visual studio solution?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have two C# projects: A and B.

- A is a desktop project (Windows Forms Application)
- B a REST service project (asp.net Web-API).

I put them both in a single visual studio professional 2013 solution.

However, though B smoothly runs on the web server (IIS-express), I cannot run A because visual studio seems to assume it's also a web application and only offers me to run it on IIS-express (though this project has program.cs class which brings in a `static void main(...){}` method).

Two questions:

1. Can you put two projects of different nature (a desktop project and a web project) in the same solution?
2. Shouldn't visual studio automatically realize A is a desktop project?

Comment: Hi Grant, thanks a lot for your hint !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure you can have 2 projects from different types in one solution ( this is what the solution is made for).

And you should be able to run your **A** project regardless of **B** ..

`Right click` on the project => `Debug` => `Start New Instance`

Comment: Hi Bakri ! thanks for your prompt response, it's really handy. cheers!

Comment: I normally set them as default project to debug projects separately. It is the first time I try the method you mention on VS 2010. I think "regardless" is inappropriate. As I try, a project debugger pause, the other project debugger will pause also.